# SwiftUI How can I get the correct font size for CATextLayer

Tags: swift, swiftui, cat, uifont, catextlayer

I am using SWiftUI and have a video editing application . A person selects a video and we display it along with the date the video was taken . The initial overlay is size 14 and if the person saves that video along with the date we are noticing that the date in the saved video is smaller than the overlay sized 14 . Can someone give suggestions on how to correct this issue ?

This is the Overlay

```
struct DateOverlay: View {
    @Binding var DateColor: Color
    @State var DateOfVideo: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        Text(DateOfVideo)
            .foregroundColor(DateColor)
            .font(.custom("Helvetica", size: 14))
    }
}
```

Then when the video gets saved this is the function responsible for the position of the overlay and the size of the overlay text on the saved video .

```
func DateTextLayer(Composition: AVMutableVideoComposition, videoModel: VideoModel,NaturalSize: CGSize) -> CATextLayer {
    
    let textLayer = CATextLayer()
    textLayer.string = videoModel.VideoDate
    textLayer.foregroundColor = videoModel.DateColor?.cgColor
    textLayer.alignmentMode = .center
    textLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale

    let scaleFactor = UIScreen.main.scale
    print("Scale Factor is \(scaleFactor)") // 3
    let adjustedFontSize = 14.0 * scaleFactor // Adjusted for screen scale this still makes it too small
    textLayer.fontSize = adjustedFontSize
    textLayer.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: adjustedFontSize)
    textLayer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: NaturalSize.width, height: 100)
    textLayer.position = CGPoint(x: Composition.renderSize.width / 2, y: Composition.renderSize.height / 2)

    return textLayer
}
```

I am not sure how the conversion should go, I know that I can manually increase the scaleFactor but then that would defeat the purpose since we will have different videos saved . Any suggestion would be great

This is the Overlay
[image: OverLay]

This is the font size when saved

[image: Saved]

This is the difference side by side

[image: Difference]

Comment: If you want to match the DateOverlay directly, I would recommend using an [ImageRenderer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/imagerenderer/) to generate a CGImage of it. Then you don't need to worry about keeping them in sync. (Without seeing the rest of your code, my first guess would be that you're setting [`renderScale`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avvideocomposition/1615786-renderscale) on your composition to 3, when it should be 1. I recommend getting rid of all of your scaling. AVVideoCompositions generally are not tied to the screen resolution.)

Comment: I thought that ImageRenderer was only for images, I have not used it since I am saving videos . I am using AVMutableVideoComposition

Comment: ImageRenderer can take (almost) any View and convert it to a CGImage. You can then composite that with a CALayer (rather than a CATextLayer). `renderScale` on a AVMutableVideoComposition should always be 1 unless you're tying it to a AVPlayerItem (which I assume you're not). I'm not sure this by itself will fix your issue, but we can get it to a simpler version with fewer scalings (I expect none, and almost certainly none that are based on UIScreen, since the device's screen has nothing to do with a video you're saving).